# How to call a function that mutates a variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

The standard method would be something like

```
foo = bar(foo)
```

But I'd like some kind of way to simply write

```
bar(foo)
```

That would change the value of `foo` like the first line. In C++ I could do this with pointers, but with Ruby I don't know how to.

Comment: Ruby doesn't have pointers, so you can't do such things here.

Comment: You can say things like `def m(s); s.gsub!(...);end` to change an argument even though Ruby is pass-by-value (where the values are references). You can also do ugly things like `h[:arg] = 6; m(h)` and end up with a different `h[:arg]`. Not recommended but sometimes unpleasant things are necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in Ruby.  You'll have to write `foo = bar(foo)`.

Another option would be to let `foo` be a mutable object.  Then `bar` could call methods on it to mutate it.  For example, if `foo` is a String, Hash, or Array, `bar` could call `foo.replace` to modify the object that `foo` refers to.

Comment: That wouldn't mutate the variable, though. It would mutate the object.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. What you are looking for is some form of pass-by-reference. However, Ruby is strictly pass-by-value.